# Problem with hyperref, sidewaysfigure and LuaLaTeX

Tags: hyperref, luatex

I have a landscape figure inserted in a `sidewaysfigure` environment with a reference in the caption. If I compile the document with `pdfLaTeX` all works well but if I compile with `LuaLaTeX` the red square link generated by `hyperref` is in the wrong position (see image below).

**Minimal Example**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
A = B\label{eq:aaa}
\end{equation}


\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-b}
\caption{Quisque quis libero id dui laoreet blandit. Aenean eleifend viverra lectus, at dcascadsc sd dafvd a sdvpellentesque lorem rhoncus eq. \ref{eq:aaa} ras justo purus }
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

**Result of compilation with LuaLaTeX**

[image]

Comment: Interestingly, the problem disappears if `hyperref` is loaded with the option `colorlinks`.  Aside: The `rotating` package automatically loads `graphicx` -- hence no need to load `graphicx` separately.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as the issue is not reproducible with an up-to-date TL2018.